# Cancel Button UI Prompt

Tags: google-apps-script, prompt, cancel-button

So I am having a little problem with my a prompt dialog I am making. The way this code works is whenever someone hits cancel on the ui prompt, it cancels the first prompt, but then the second prompt appears. Is there a way to make it so that when someone hits the cancel button is cancels both prompts? I am not sure if that makes any sense, but here is my code.

```
function Cancel() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'What Day Was Safe Rides Cancelled?',
      'Please Enter the Date as mm/dd/yyy.',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var result2 = ui.prompt(
      'What is the Reason for the Cancellation?',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var text2 = result2.getResponseText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Nightly Stats'),
    row = sheet.getLastRow();

  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
      sheet.getRange(row+1,1).setValue(text).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      sheet.getRange(row+1,2,1,6).setValue(text2).setHorizontalAlignment("center").mergeAcross();
      sheet.getRange(row+1,8).setValue("1").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    ui.alert('The Cancellation has Been Recorded');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show the second prompt only after the first prompt's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to move the "result2" prompt logic into the `if (button == ui.Button.OK) {...}` section.

Also, I would recommend refactoring the "insertData" stuff into it's own function, so the button/prompt logic is easier to follow.

Something like this:

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function Cancel() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // first prompt
  var result = ui.prompt(
    "What Day Was Safe Rides Cancelled?",
    "Please Enter the Date as mm/dd/yyy.",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();

  // User clicked "OK" on first prompt
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // second prompt
    var result2 = ui.prompt(
      "What is the Reason for the Cancellation?",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
    );
    var button2 = result2.getSelectedButton();
    var text2 = result2.getResponseText();

    // user clicked "OK" on second prompt
    if (button2 == ui.Button.OK) {
      insertData(text, text2);
    }
  }
}

function insertData(text, text2) {
  // get last row in nightly stats sheet
  var sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Nightly Stats");
  row = sheet.getLastRow();

  // insert data into sheet
  sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
  sheet
    .getRange(row + 1, 1)
    .setValue(text)
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  sheet
    .getRange(row + 1, 2, 1, 6)
    .setValue(text2)
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
    .mergeAcross();
  sheet
    .getRange(row + 1, 8)
    .setValue("1")
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There was just a little bug where it said "text is not defined", but that was an easy fix. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Right, I forgot to pass the text along. Edited the answer. Glad that works for you!